# While loop not working in program with boolean (C++)

Tags: c++

Hi I was writing a simple program that asks for user input within a certain range.  I used a boolean to start the while loop, but when I try declaring the boolean false in the first if statement, it doesn't end the loop and the program keeps asking for a user input.  I've thought about using a break but shouldn't negating the condition stop the loop?

```
    int num; 
    cout << "Enter a number";
    bool invNum= true;
    while (invNum = true)
    {
        cin >> num;

        if (num >= 0 && num <= 20)
        {
            cout << "You typed: " << num << endl;
            invNum = false;
            //break;
        }

        if (num <= 0 || num >= 20)
        {
            cout << "Type another number: ";
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Turn your compiler warning level up and the error should be evident.

Comment: `while (invNum = true)` should be ` while (invNum == true)` or just ` while (invNum)`. ` while (invNum = true)` assigns `invNum` to `true` instead of checking if it is `true`

Comment: Write your conditional expressions with the bool constant on the left and you will have fewer of these issues. while (true = invNum) will not compile and you will realize the mistake and change it to while (true == invNum).

Comment: You may not even require to compare in this instance since invNum is a bool you should be able to check the condition with  'while (invNum) {}' and save yourself from assignment/comparison. It is important to learn the differences though.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is not used for comparison. You should use `==`. Change `while (invNum = true)` to `while (invNum == true)` or better to write `while (true == invNum)`

Answer (score 2):

```
while (invNum = true)
```

Here is the problem.

It should read:

```
while (invNum == true)
```

What you're currently doing is assigning `true` to `invNum`. The assignment statement `invNum = true` returns the value of `invNum` after it has been set to `true`, in effect resulting in a `while(true)` loop.